# How to prove this tautology using only logical equivalences?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm having trouble with this problem.

> Using logical equivalencies prove that $(p \land q)\implies (p \lor q)$ is a tautology.

Comment: A tautology is a "trivial" statement in which $A \rightarrow B$ and $B \rightarrow A$.  In your case, though, the reverse need not hold:  $(p \vee q) \rightarrow (p \wedge q)$ need not hold.

Comment: It is a tautology.  However it is not clear what "logical equivalenc[es]" you intend to use.  It would be enough to note that (for example), $(p\land q) \implies p$ and in turn $p \implies (p\lor q)$.  But these are not "logical equivalences" as I understand the phrase.

Answer (score 2):

According to the equivalence $(a\rightarrow b) \Longleftrightarrow \neg a\vee b$, the De Morgan's laws, the associativity and commutativity of the logical operator $\vee$, one has

\begin{align*}
(p\wedge q) \longrightarrow (p\vee q) & \Longleftrightarrow \neg(p\wedge q)\vee(p\vee q) \Longleftrightarrow (\neg p\vee \neg q)\vee(p\vee q)\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (\neg p\vee p)\vee(\neg q\vee q) \Longleftrightarrow t\vee t \Longleftrightarrow t
\end{align*}

where $t$ represents a tautology.

Answer (score 0):

$T$

$\Leftrightarrow T \vee T$

$\Leftrightarrow (p \vee \neg p) \vee (q \vee \neg q) \Leftrightarrow T$

We drop the parentheses because the statement is well defined...

$\Leftrightarrow p \vee \neg p \vee q \vee \neg q \Leftrightarrow T$

$\Leftrightarrow \neg p \vee \neg q \vee p \vee q \Leftrightarrow T$

$\Leftrightarrow (\neg p \vee \neg q) \vee (p \vee q) \Leftrightarrow T$

$\Leftrightarrow \neg (p \wedge q) \vee (p \vee q) \Leftrightarrow T$

$\Leftrightarrow (p \wedge q) \rightarrow (p \vee q) \Leftrightarrow T$

---

However, I prefer a proof via natural deduction because it is cleaner...

$1.$ $p \wedge q$ ACP

$2.$ $(p \wedge q) \vee p$ by disjunction introduction $1$

$3.$ $p \vee (p \wedge q)$ by commutative rule $2$

$4.$ $(p \vee p) \wedge (p \vee q)$ by distributive rule $3$

$5.$ $p \wedge (p \vee q)$ by idempotence $4$

$6.$ $p \vee q$ by conjunction elimination $5$

$7.$ $(p \wedge q) \rightarrow (p \vee q)$ CP $1$-$6$

Answer (score -2):

A tautology is a statement that is always 'True'.

In your case you have two variables, each may take the value of either 'true' or 'false'.

You may simply plug these four cases in your expression and get 'True' in each case you try. Note that your logical expression is a composition of three operations, i.e. 'and', 'or' and 'implies'. Please, check with Wikipedia for their truth tables.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_ponens

Comment: uhm, i'm trying to prove that it is a tautology without using any truth tables.

Comment: Come on... all binary operators are defined as truth functions of two variables based on the truth tables. Even De Morgan's laws or whatever. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table